# how to make 2 columns in a matrix a date-time object for subtraction

Tags: r, datetime

I have read in a .csv in R as so:

```
data <- read.csv("dataset.csv", header=TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

When I do `typeof(data)` it output is `"list"`.

Data has `dim` of `72781 x 3`. The three columns being `Id`, `Closed Date`, and `Creation Date`. Both `Closed Date` and `Creation Date` contain fields which a string dates with its time, as so: `"May 9, 2018 8:38 PM"`

However, some fields in `Closed Date` are empty like so, `""`.

My goal is to subtract `Closed Date` with `Creation Date` for each sample in the data and store them in another column.

I would like to fill all fields in `Closed Date` whose fields are `""` with todays current date.

The following code is what I wrote in attempt to do the subtraction but it did not work:

```
data_matrix <- as.matrix(data)
creationDate <- c(data_matrix[,3], format = '%B %d, %Y')
closedDate <- c(data_matrix[,2], format = '%B %d, %Y')
```

So when I print the first field in `creationDate` it outputs :

```
creationDate[1]                    
"Jun 5, 2018 3:21 PM"
```

Also the code I wrote ignores the time...

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: don't convert it to `matrix`.  Keep it in a `data.frame`

Comment: While `typeof(mydataframe)` returns "list", `class(mydataframe)` returns "data.frame". Recall an R data.frame is a list of equal length atomic vectors.